# Python script taking too much memory

Tags: python, linux, memory

For debugging purposes, I'd like to see the approximate memory size of each living variable in my python script, because a variable is growing up quickly in size (or multiple variables are created but not destroyed).

### EDIT 1:

Here is the output of [Guppy-PE](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) (total variables size ~54MB) at the moment when used memory grows by 6GB.

```
Partition of a set of 370715 objects. Total size = 54137008 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 151088  41 16953320  31  16953320  31 str
     1  91788  25  8121344  15  25074664  46 tuple
     2  16472   4  4979464   9  30054128  56 unicode
     3   4699   1  3118216   6  33172344  61 dict (no owner)
     4    895   0  3100648   6  36272992  67 dict of module
     5  23616   6  3022848   6  39295840  73 types.CodeType
     6  23707   6  2844840   5  42140680  78 function
     7   2412   1  2303520   4  44444200  82 dict of type
     8   2412   1  2178768   4  46622968  86 type
     9  12733   3  1805096   3  48428064  89 list
<925 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

I suspect a library ([Wand](http://wand-py.org)) that uses an external lib(`libmagickwand-dev`). but don't know at what level in my code this is happening.

is there a better way to debug this kind of problems ?

### EDIT 2

I can see those 6GB in `htop` but not in `Guppy-PE`:

[image: htop]

Comment: A crude (yet often effective) way to debug something like this is to comment out some part, see if the problem occurs, if not, comment out some more, etc. At some point (hopefully) the problem should stop appearing, at which point you should have a reasonable indication of where the problem is... If it's in an external C library, then it may be a bug in that library...